# Class Controller does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and I'm just following some tutorial blogs but I'm stuck at early stage.

Here is my Route

```
Route::resource('ip', 'IpController');
Route::get("index","IpController@view");
```

and here is my controller

```
<?php

class IpController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```

here is how I access the page

```
<a href="{{ URL() }}/ip/index">IP</a>
```

I do what the tutorials says but I'm confused why I've got this error when accessing the page.

***Class IpController does not exist***

May i know what i've done wrong and how can i fix it? TIA!

Comment: Whenever you createa a new class, run composer dump-autoload (if you're not following psr-4, ofcourse).

Comment: @Dave solve this problem or not because i am also face this problem and not found any solution. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue when using Lumen, not Laravel. So I thought answering here would be helpful to others who stumble onto this page as well. I apologize in advance if that is not in keeping with the SO rules.

Here's the error I got in Lumen:

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Controller does not exist'
```

The solution is: when defining the route, use the full path to the controller:

```
$app->get('/someRoute/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in CLI:

`composer dump autoload`

and remove the second route because it isn't necessary because it's  already declared in your Resource route.
and change

`class IpController extends BaseController` into

`class IpController extends eController` if you are using Laravel 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('ip', 'IpController');
```

will automatically create the

```
Route::get("ip","IpController@index");
```

for you, along with [many more helpful routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Then you can make the link to it like that:

```
<a href="{{ URL('ip') }}">IP</a>
```

(Because the auto-generated route made be `Route::resource` uses just the `www.mysite.com/ip` for "index page" for the "ip"s.

Also, in laravel 5, make sure that your controller lies in: `yourapp/app/Http/Controllers/` directory.

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)[laravel-5](/questions/tagged/laravel-5)

Comment: Hi, I follow all of this and this what ive got

BadMethodCallException

Method [show] does not exist.

Comment: Can you give the list of your routes? You can do this by using the command-line command: `php artisan route:list`<br/>

Comment: edit: I think I got your problem: you are accessing the page with url like: `www.yoursite.com/ip/something` then laravel thinks that you want to **show** one of the **ip**, which handled (when using the benefits of `Route::resource`) by the method `show` in your Controller, which indeed doesn't exist...

Comment: Hi but i also try using this route
Route::get("index","IpController@index"); but still same problem

Comment: What is the URL of the page which is giving you that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a namespace.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class IpController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

}
```